# Using INDIRECT in Array Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I use this arrayformula along with **INDIRECT** because it is the only way I know to maintain my references since the reference sheet has in the script to routinely add another row to sheet Data!.  How can I either add to the below formula to only show values in the array that are above the value in `$CQ$17` and below the value in `$CQ$16`?  Can this be done without increasing my sheets processing time since it updates every minute?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Data!E"&13+$F$7&":E"&597+$F$7))
```

Comment: Are the values in CQ16 and CQ17 dates?  IF so there is a much eaiser way to do this without INDIRECT() but you would need to share a sample of the way the data comes in from the script and a sample of the way you'd like to see the data analyzed/displayed.

Comment: No, they are numbers.

Comment: would still help to see a sample.  A real sample would be great, but even a screenshot could be helpful.  Sheets don't usually get that wide without good reason :)

Comment: I don't think a sample is necessary.  A lot of effort goes into trying to present a sample from my project.  This seems like a pretty simple request.

Comment: I think it would be necessary to add a sample of the expected outcome, at least in the form of a screenshot.

Comment: fair enough if you don't want to share a sample.  Hopefully someone else will understand your simple request without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you do not need no `INDIRECT` and could use either `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(
  OFFSET(Data!E13, $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1, 1),
  "
    select E
    where E > " & $CQ$17 & " and
          E < " & $CQ$16,
  -1
)
```

or `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(
  OFFSET(Data!E13, $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1),
  OFFSET(Data!E13, $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1) > $CQ$17,
  OFFSET(Data!E13, $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1) < $CQ$16
)
```

Those three times constructing the same range are not good, I would go with `QUERY`.

A sample sheet would be really helpful though.

Comment: Thanks!  I know you said it would be best to use the Query example, but it gave an error of "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col1.  I am not sure the problem so I will use the Filter example unless you know right off what might be causing the error.

Comment: That works.  I had to add the indirect back in because script inserts a row every minute which would otherwise drop Data!E13 to Data!E14 and so forth.  So here is my final formula unless there is a better way of adding the indirect reference.  Thank you so much for your help.  =QUERY(
  OFFSET(INDIRECT("Data!E13"), $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1, 1),
  "
    select E
    where E > " & $CQ$17 & " and
          E < " & $CQ$16,
  -1
)

Comment: I do not really get it. Those should be exactly the same: `INDIRECT("Data!E13")` and `Data!E13`. Maybe it is better to set a Named Range for example for `Data!E13` and then use it in the formula? Although I am no sure how your script works, whether it will mess with named range or not...