# Construct a Query to Reference Indirect Array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So I have this formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Data!A"&13+$F$7&":A"&597+$F$7))
```

to reference dates in another sheet `Data!`.  I just submitted a separate request [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489475/using-indirect-in-array-formula/61503457#61503457) which is similar.

Difference in this case is I need it to return the entire array. First part would likely be the following, but I have no clue what the query language ought to be.  Thank you for your help.

```
=QUERY(
  OFFSET(INDIRECT("Data!E13"), $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1, 1),
 Query language
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("Data!E13"), $F$7, 0, 597 - 13 + 1, 1)
```